# Latex Error: Unicode char ： (U+FF1A)

Tags: xetex

I want to type this sympol `$\log\phi$` , which should look like:
[image], but the error occurs:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ： (U+FF1A)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I checked online, some people say `Use [utf8] instead of [utf8x]`, thus I change`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` as `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but it doesn't work. Any solution is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The problematic character is U+FF1A, FULLWIDTH COLON, which doesn't seem connected with the input `$\log\phi$`

Comment: @egreg Thank you, but how to solve that?

Comment: I assume somewhere you have a copied/pasted colon from another source (webpage, Word document, etc.). Replace it with a colon typed in your TeX editor, and that should handle it. This assumes you have no other reason to include Unicode characters in your document.

Comment: Copy the colon from the error message and use your editor's facilities for finding and removing it.

Comment: Thank you so much!! @egreg  and @ Mike Renfro, That's true! I copy some text from a pdf, and the colon is not in the tex format.